# What languages should I use to allow users to increase or decrease an image size on a webpage?

Tags: html, css, interactive

I am interested in having +/- buttons to increase and decrease the size of an image. What programming languages could I use, and what would be the pros/cons for using each one? I apologize for my incredibly novice questions.

Comment: Javascript is for you

Comment: Check [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/image-manipulation/). Using Jquery. Just install the plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bored, so I decided to build this simple stuff for ya! Please buy be a beer.
HTML:

```
    <img src="http://camcimcumcem.com/tphotos/5001_10000/Square-4.jpg"><br>
    <span id="plus">+</span><br>
    <span id="minus">-</span>
```

Script:

```
$("#plus").click(function(){
    $("img").css({"height": "+=50px", "width": "+=50px"});
})

$("#minus").click(function(){
    $("img").css({"height": "-=50px", "width": "-=50px"});
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YoshiMaster/kxjezr5e/2/)